# Restart only a single Rails app running on Passenger / nginx on VPS hosting many passenger apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, vps, digital-ocean

I am running multiple rails apps and a sinatra app under the same domain on a VPS using nginx and passenger.  When I deploy code I need to restart the application process for the app that got updated.  Right now I'm running `service nginx stop` followed by `service nginx start` thereby restarting all the passenger processes.  It seems silly to have to restart nginx instead of a just the target passenger process.  Is there a way to do such a thing?

Here's my nginx.conf file:  https://gist.github.com/srt32/8535548.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Goto the root of your Rails application and touch a tmp/restart.txt file.

```
touch /webapps/mycook/tmp/restart.txt
```

Remove restart.txt once application is restarted, not mandatory though.

Reference - http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_redeploying_restarting_the_ruby_on_rails_application